# How to integrate paypal for multiple sellers in IOS SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I have to integrate PayPal SDK in my eCommerce IOS application

My concern is

I have multiple sellers in application and if customers purchase products from  two different seller then how can I credit both sellers account with customer paypal account at a time.

Please advice...

Comment: Buyer  can buy multiple items at a time which belongs to different sellers in your app..?

Comment: No.  Buyer will buy multiple sellers items separately but each seller will require to create app on https://developer.paypal.com and provide credentials in app. Is there another way of doing this ?

Comment: YES..First create app at developer.apple.com and generate Live & Sandbox Keys/credentials. Sellers must have an account with paypal.com with their bank details stored in it. We can supply the seller email as receiver email for payment. Then amount will credit to seller account directly from buyer account..No need to create app by sellers. Just they need login email and bank details linked with paypal...!

Comment: thanks  @Vidhyanand900  for comment. I am integrating now fingers crossed !

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below links for Single Payment using Paypal(Single Seller - Single Buyer)

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/mobile-sdk-overview/

For Chained Payments -- Single Buyer & Multiple Receivers

https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages/tree/gh-pages/MPL

https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_mpl_developer_guide_and_reference_iphone.pdf

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/gs_MPL/

Hope it is useful...